# File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap (Bootstrap, Rails, Sass error)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, sass

This is my `application.css.scss`

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 *= require social-share-button
 */
```

I am using this gem - https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

Per the instructions, this is my `:assets` group in my Gemfile:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
  gem "font-awesome-rails"
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
  gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
end
```

I created a file called `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss`, which has this:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap-responsive";
@import "font-awesome";
```

This is the error:

```
Sass::SyntaxError at /
File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets.
/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss:1)
```

This is my `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require social-share-button
//= require_tree .
```

I have restarted my server many times, and viewed my app from an Incognito window.

I am using Rails 4.1.1 and Ruby 2.1.1.

Any suggestions?

**Update 1:**

For what it's worth, this is what my `app/assets/stylesheets/` looks like:

```
$ ls
application.css.scss            bootstrap.css               font-awesome.min.css
bootstrap-social.css            bootstrap.min.css           locations.css.scss
bootstrap-theme.css         bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss    main.css
bootstrap-theme.min.css         font-awesome.css            posts.css.scss
```

Comment: This issue relates to any sass file you want to import, not just bootstrap.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I figured out the issue here.

The problem is I am using an `:assets` group. That was removed in Rails 4.

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-3-2-to-rails-4-0-gemfile

```
**4.2 Gemfile**
Rails 4.0 removed the assets group from Gemfile. You'd need to remove that line from your Gemfile when upgrading.
```

Once I pulled them out of the assets group, deleted my `Gemfile.lock` and ran `bundle install`...everything worked perfectly.

Hope this helps some other poor soul.

Answer (score 7):

I just experienced the same problem

```
File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets
```

I tried restarting the development server and running "rails s" again and it worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but what fixed it for me was:

- Kill rails server
- Add instruction *gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.6'* into my Gemfile
- Run the *bundle install* command at the server terminal
- Restart rails server

However, just to note that I am using the latest version of rails -  Rails 5.0.1 so unlike version 4.2, I didn't have to worry about removing the asset do instruction within the Gemfile

Comment: I'm confused by this solution. Isn't the bootstrap-sass gem for Bootstrap 3, while the bootstrap gem is for Bootstrap 4? It seems odd that there would be a dependency on the earlier gem, or am I just missing something?

Answer (score -2):

this worked for me

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', :git => 'https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass.git', :branch => 'next'
```